# Difference between Clustered and standalone server?

Tags: java, deployment, weblogic, cluster-computing

Is there any difference between deploying application in a stand alone server and deploying the application in a clustered environment ?

I am asking this question because I am deploying one application which is working in the standalone server but is not working in the clustered environment!!

Thanks!

Comment: There's plenty of differences. How they affect you depends on your application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application not working on a Clustered Environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055310/application-not-working-on-a-clustered-environment)

Comment: Yeah, I have the same problem. But nobody has answered there!

Answer (score 0):

Clustered server environment might need some extra setup. Refer to your application server's documentation for this. Most probably you don't have broadcasting set up properly. The deployment process does not differ from standalone.

Comment: I mean this is my main issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055310/application-not-working-on-a-clustered-environment